# How to use Cython in WSL/WSL2 with Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

I'm trying to run Cython in WSL/WSL2 using Pycharm, but I'm not sure how to make that work. The [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-setup-py.html) for `Run setup.py Task` do not work in a WSL environment; it tries to build in Windows instead of in WSL. Can anyone walk me through this or point me at some resources that do?

Comment: Are you running PyCharm from within WSL2 or Windows?

Comment: PyCharm is running in Windows but has the WSL interpreter configured for the project.

Comment: I've had problems in the past trying to run PyCharm on Windows using WSL interpreter. The best solution was to run PyCharm from within WSL using something like VcXsrv for Windows to forward the GUI from X11 to Windows.

Comment: PyCharm works fine in Windows using the WSL interpreter, my only problem is when working with Cython.